# How to extract json within the html comment tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract `json` content within the html comment tag using BeautifulSoup.

```
<script data_id ="dfsfre2323" data_key="23424sfsfsfdafd", type="application/json"><!--
{"employee": {"name":"sonoo", "salary":56000, "married":true}}--></script>]
```

The output should be as follows

```
Name: sonoo
Salary: 56000
Married: True
```

I have tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import json
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
data = soup.find("script", {"type":"application/json", data_id ="dfsfre2323" data_key="23424sfsfsfdafd"})                                                                                                       
comment = soup.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(data, Comment))
```

I don't get nothing in the comment.

Any help appreciated in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content inside `<script>` tag isn't parsed by BeautifulSoup, so your `.find(text=...)` won't find anything. Convert the script string to BeautifulSoup before `.find()`:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


txt = '''
<script data_id ="dfsfre2323" data_key="23424sfsfsfdafd" type="application/json"><!--
    {"employee": {"name":"sonoo", "salary":56000, "married":true}}
--></script>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")
data = soup.find("script", {"type":"application/json", 'data_id':"dfsfre2323", 'data_key':"23424sfsfsfdafd"})
comment = BeautifulSoup(data.string, "html.parser").find(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))

data = json.loads(comment)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "employee": {
        "name": "sonoo",
        "salary": 56000,
        "married": true
    }
}
```